# Handling zero sales on public holidays when forecasting daily data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have daily sales data for about 3 years, and I need to forecast the next month. However, zero sales occur during public holidays and weekends. I can easily remove the weekends, so that I have a periodicity of 5, but I don't know how to handle the public holidays that happen on a weekday (e.g. Tuesday), when building a model. Does anyone know a standard method for doing this?

Comment: A good model can detect and effectively replace anomalies using methods called Intervention Detection . See http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html

Comment: If you are using the R implementation of arima (or some other that accepts NA's in the data), then you can just replace the structural zeros with NA.